# error in push notification

Tags: php, urbanairship.com

I am trying to implement urban airship and started with simple php code. but is is giving me error .
my php code:

```
<?php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
use UrbanAirship\Airship;
use UrbanAirship\Push as P;

$airship = new Airship("key", "secret");
$response = $airship->push()
    ->setAudience(P\deviceToken(""))
    ->setNotification(P\notification("Hello from php!"))
    ->setDeviceTypes(P\all)
    ->send();

print "Push sent!. Push IDs:" . $response.push_ids;
```

error :
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'UrbanAirship\AirshipException' with message 'Airship request failed: 401 on POST to https://go.urbanairship.com/api/push/' in C:\xampp\htdocs\phpProjects\notify\vendor\urbanairship\urbanairship\src\UrbanAirship\AirshipException.php:17 Stack trace: #0

Comment: 401 would mean :: No access credentials were supplied, or they are either incorrect or insufficient for the call you're making. Double check the application key and secret, and see if the API call you're making requires the master secret.

Comment: @Sudhir what is the difference between secret and master secret ?? please explain

Comment: Secret is string for identifying the app setup secret and Master Secret is string used for server to server API access

Comment: 401 is unauthorized. Check your authorizations in the headers.

Answer (score 0):

The error was because `key` and `secret` were not given while making the airship Object. The problem was solved after supplying the key and secret